# ReactJs Failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

./src/index.js 1:72
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:72)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/fujitsu/Desktop/Odin Project/WHERE'S WALDO/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
> | $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
> |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.